# NSArray sorting issue with acronyms being sorted first

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have an NSArray that I would like to sort alphabetically and I am currently using `sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector (localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)`. This returns

```
CAA
CBL
CCC
Cab
Car
Cat
```

The acronyms are alphabetized first, followed by the others. What would I use to sort so that the acronyms are sorted along with the regular words? Can't seem to find the answer in Apple's docs.

`book = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr
```

And create your NSComparator for the desired behavior.

Like this:

```
NSarray *sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
  //Decide in the order
  if (yourCondition)
  {
  return NSOrderedSame
  }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar. Could you elaborate? My full code is `book = [[self.sections valueForKey:[[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer... I've never used NSComparator so I need to work this out to see if it works. I'll let you know. It's surprising to me why acronyms are bundled first...